# Django Pagination from ?page= to /page/

Tags: django

I have this view:

```
class PageView(ListView):
    # ... code ...
    paginate_by = 4
```

In template I have something like:

```
<div class="pagination">
          <span class="page-links">
              {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                  <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
              {% endif %}
              <span class="page-current">
                  Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
              </span>
              {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                  <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
              {% endif %}
          </span>
        </div>
```

How can I transform GET variable `?page=number` to look like `/page/number/` in django?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? Pagination usually is done via querystring parameters.

Comment: Actually, I'm working on a mini-blog and it wouldn't be so good with all the posts displayed on a single page.
I don't get it, how do you do that via querystring parameters?
 Anyway, I've already solved that... check my answer below. I wanted a simple solution, without complicated methods and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot test it now but you should be able to re-use all of `ListView`.

Have a look at `django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin#paginate_queryset`:

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):
    """
    Paginate the queryset, if needed.
    """
    paginator = self.get_paginator(
        queryset, page_size, orphans=self.get_paginate_orphans(),
        allow_empty_first_page=self.get_allow_empty())
    page_kwarg = self.page_kwarg

    # HERE
    page = self.kwargs.get(page_kwarg) or self.request.GET.get(page_kwarg) or 1

    try:
        page_number = int(page)
    except ValueError:
        if page == 'last':
            page_number = paginator.num_pages
        else:
            raise Http404(_("Page is not 'last', nor can it be converted to an int."))
    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_number)
        return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
    except InvalidPage as e:
        raise Http404(_('Invalid page (%(page_number)s): %(message)s') % {
            'page_number': page_number,
            'message': str(e)
        })
```

This means that Django looks for the page number first in the view's `kwargs`, and then in the `get` parameters.

The values in `self.kwargs` come from the view's own `**kwargs` - see `django.views.generic.base.View#as_view`. This means you should be able to just define a URL like `url(r'^event/(?P<page>'d+)/$'` and use it with your existing CBV - it should pick up the page number on its own.

Comment: I get `NoReverseMatch at /events/1/`. I have set `page_kwarg = 'page'`. It's not working.

Comment: Oh, damn. It wasn't working because in my `base.html` I have used something like: 
`{% url 'events' %}` without <page> argument.
Is there a way to put a default value to /events/ ? Because it's raising an error.

Comment: Now I noticed that `or 1` for `page` variable, but still not working when i go to `/events/`. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

for example, you can use view function:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def listOfSomethinView(request, page):
    paginator(Something.objects.all(), 10)
    try:
        list_of_something = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        list_of_something = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        list_of_something = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'path_to_your_template', {
        'list_of_something': list_of_something,
    })
```

in urls.py add this:

```
url(r'^event/(?P<page>[0-9]{1,10})/$', views.listOfSomethingView, name='listOfSomething')
```

in your template use something like this

```
{% url 'app:listOfSomething' paginator.previous_page_number %}
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but I still want to use class-based view. I want to keep things simple. I will wait for other answers. Thanks.

Comment: you can also do it with class-based views https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context

Answer (score 0):

OK. I solved it.
Actually when I had:

```
url(r'^events/(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$', views.PageView.as_view(), name='events'),
```

It raises an error because `page` argument is missing and `urls.py` doesn't know `/events/` path.

So, in my url mapping (urls.py) I've written:

```
url(r'^events/$', views.PageView.as_view(), name='events'),
url(r'^events/(?P<page>[a-z0-9]+)/$', views.PageView.as_view(), name='events'),
```

When I go to `/events/`, no arguments needed, `page` is set to `1` because no `page_kwarg` is provided, all good.

When I go to `/events/<page>/`, takes that variable and finally it's working.

Edit: I put `[a-z0-9]` instead of `[0-9]` because it's needed when you access `/events/last/`. In url template tag I must provide `last` as a string: `{% url 'events' 'last' %}`

Thanks for answers, If you think my solution is not good, please comment below my answer.

Sorry for my grammar.